# How to make two text fields in one container like this?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

How to make two text fields like middle screen in this picture: [image: Simple]

Of course in this sample it list, with Labels, but I want make simulate control with TextFields. How I can make this?

Comment: Do you mean a table view with 2 cells that each have a text field in them?

Comment: No. Only two text fields. With table view I try and fail it.

Comment: But in that image, it's a table view. What *have* you tried? Can you show us some code?

Comment: http://cs5613.userapi.com/u06492/docs/145b06488cea/Login.png like in this picture. Real primer.

Comment: Again, a table view. If you've tried a table view and it didn't work for you - show us some code where it was going wrong.

Comment: I think need remove bottom corners rom top textfield, and top corners remove from bottom textfield. But I not found this option.

Comment: Set the `borderStyle` of the text field to `UITextBorderStyleNone`.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3185483/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-09%20at%2014.08.56%20.png text view + 2 text fields.

Comment: OK, so set the border style to none on both of those text fields for a start. And is the table view set to grouped style?

Comment: if I set border none, in text fields boreders become transparent.

Comment: Yes that's right. That's what you want though, right? What you're trying to do is get 2 *table cells* each with a single text field in it that has no border. That's what you've shown in the image anyway.

Comment: big thanks, I understood how to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a tableview with the style is group, and have a hardview in table, one section with three cells

Comment: Read comments to question please, I added really example.